# Getting a std::string or C string from a QString representing an arbitrary filename on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, unicode, mingw

I'm using `QFileDialog::getOpenFileName()` to have the user select a file, but I need the result to be a C string, since I have to pass it to something written in C which uses `fopen()`. I cannot change this.

The problem I'm finding is that, on Windows/MinGW, using `toStdString()` on the resulting `QString` doesn't work well with Unicode/non-ASCII filenames. Trying to open the file based on the `std::string` fails, because some character set conversion seems to be occurring. Sometimes using `toLocal8Bit()` to convert works, but sometimes it doesn't.

Consider the following (MinGW) program:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

#include <QApplication>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QFile>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    auto filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName();
    QFile f(filename);

    std::cout << "fopen: " << (std::fopen(filename.toStdString().c_str(), "r") != nullptr) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "fopen (local8bit): " << (std::fopen(filename.toLocal8Bit().data(), "r") != nullptr) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Qt can open: " << f.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly) << std::endl;
}
```

- For a file called `☢.txt`, `toStdString()` works, `local8Bit()` doesn't.
- For a file called `ä.txt`, `toStdString()` doesn't work, `local8Bit()` does.
- For a file called `Ȁ.txt`, neither works.

In all cases, though, `QFile` is able to open the file. I suppose it's probably using Unicode Windows functions while the C code is using `fopen()`, which, to my understanding is a so-called ANSI function on Windows.  But is there any way to get a “bag of bytes”, so to speak, from a `QString`?  I don't care about the encoding of the filename, I just want something that can be passed to `fopen()` to open the file.

I've found that using `GetShortPathName` to get a short filename from `filename.toWCharArray()` seems to work, but that's very cumbersome, and my understanding is that NTFS filesystems can be told not to support short names, so it's not a viable solution in general anyway.

Comment: Forget about `local8Bit()`, it's a thing from the past. That said, what do you mean with "doesn't work"?

Comment: [toStdWString](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toStdWString) passed to [_wfopen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-wfopen?view=msvc-170) is probably the most reliable approach on windows

Comment: If you just want direct access to the data, try calling [constData](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#constData).

Comment: "doesn't work" is described in the question as showing that fopen() fails to open the file, even while QFile succeeds (so the file exists).

Comment: Unfortunately for _wfopen(), I don't have control over the call to open the file.  This is getting passed elsewhere to a module expecting a char* to pass to fopen().

Comment: then you're basically stuffed, `fopen` on windows can only handle files that can be encoded in your local code page, if you want to open arbitrary files you need to use the unicode APIs

Comment: I looked at constData(), but that returns a pointer to QChar, which I can't see a way to convert, without charset issues, to a C string.  You can't just cast the QChar* because it will contain zeros for ASCII/ASCII-range values, interpreted as null bytes ending the string.

Comment: Maybe set [UTF-8 locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63454192/1983398) for your program?

Comment: @ssbssa That may well be the best approach, I'll have to investigate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File paths in the non-unicode API of Windows are either parsed in the current ANSI (Microsoft codec) codepage, or in the OEM codepage (see also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-wfope). ANSI is the default.

So your question translates to: How can I convert a UTF-8 or UTF-16 string to ANSI or OEM?

There's an answer for the ANSI conversion: [How to convert from UTF-8 to ANSI using standard c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17562736/how-to-convert-from-utf-8-to-ansi-using-standard-c)

Anyhow, it's important to realize that not all UTF strings can be represented in these more narrow codecs...

Comment: This is effectively the path I'm going, I think, using Qt's local8Bit() method, which converts a Unicode QString to a C string in the current locale.  As you note, it won't work for all characters, but it's much better than converting to UTF-8 in places UTF-8 isn't supported at all!

Comment: You're right that QString::toLocal8Bit() will by default convert to ANSI, using WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP...) internally. So yes, that should work for strings with characters that can actually be represented in the Windows encoding...